# Convert preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php

I need help in converting preg_replace to preg_replace_callback.

PHP 5.4 and above firing the following statement:
`The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in`

I've tried changing:

```
if (stripos ( $tpl->copy_template, "[category=" ) !== false) {
    $tpl->copy_template = preg_replace ( "#\\[category=(.+?)\\](.*?)\[/category\\]#ies",         "check_category('\\1', '\\2', '{$category_id}')", $tpl->copy_template );
}
```

to

```
if (stripos ( $tpl->copy_template, "[category=" ) !== false) {
    $tpl->copy_template = preg_replace_callback ( "#\\[category=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/category\\]#isu", 
        function($cat){
            return check_category($cat['1'], $cat['2'], $category_id);
        }
    , $tpl->copy_template );
}
```

the return is empty

Comment: What does `check_category` do?

Comment: checks for categories... it quite big, so i decided not to include it. `function check_category($cats, $block, $category, $action = true) {..}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$category_id` is a global variable, you have to use it inside a function with the `global` keyword. And the keys of a numeric array are integers rather than strings; so you have to write `$cat[1]` instead of `$cat['1']` and `$cat[2]` instead of `$cat['2']`.

With these minor alterations, your function becomes:

```
function($cat){
        global $category_id;
        return check_category($cat[1], $cat[2], $category_id);
}
```